# Is there a way to put an if statement within a foreach loop in a cshtml page?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, razor

I am studying mvc and user interface.
I am trying to display and check user details and if a certain variable is true, I want a bootstrap toggle on icon to appear, and if false, I want it to be a toggle off icon. So if s.Active is true, instead of true, I want the on icon. Can anyone advise on this?

````
@foreach(var s in Model.Tickets) {
           <tr>
               <td>@s.Issue</td>
               <td>@s.CreatedOn</td>
               <td>@s.Active</td>
               
           </tr>
       }```
````

Comment: You can probably just use an if-statement. But the problem is not fully clear. What icon? Where do you want to show it?

Comment: <i class="bi bi-toggle-on"></i> if s.Active is true and off if it is false. I want it displayed in the table data when the page is ran.

Answer (score 1):

ok, you can use if with for

```
@foreach(var s in Model.Tickets) {
           <tr>
               <td>@s.Issue</td>
               <td>@s.CreatedOn</td>
               <td>
               @if (s.Active)
                   {
                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1" checked>
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1"></label>
                    </div>
                   }
                else
                   {
                     <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1"></label>
                     </div>
                    }
               </td>
           </tr>
       }
```

this toggle work according to bootstrap, i used this
https://bootswatch.com/litera/

or you also could use your own toggle style

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly :)

Comment: Oh no! so much duplicate code!! This could all be done with a simple `@(s.Active?"checked":"")`....